# Routing function not being called

Tags: javascript, html, server

I am working on a simple restaurant web app which uses a mongo-db database to store the menu items. My issue is that I have a client js file that will use a routing function that then accesses the database to return all the menu items of a certain restaurant. My issue is that my endpoint for the url isn't being recognized:

Client.js

```
function readMenu(rest){
    (async () => {
        // const newURL = url + "/menus/"+rest
        const resp = await fetch(url+"/menus/"+rest)
        const j = await resp.json();


        itemlist = j["items"]
        var element = document.getElementById("menu")
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {
            var para = document.createElement("p")
            item = itemList[i]
            text = item["name"]+" | "+item["cost"]+" | "+item["descr"] +"<br>";
            var node = document.createTextNode(text)
            para.appendChild(node)
            element.appendChild(para)
        }
    })
}
```

Server-routing.ts (Routings):

```
this.router.get("/menus", this.getResturants.bind(this))
this.router.post("/menus", this.addResturaunt.bind(this))
this.router.get("/menus/:rest", this.getResturauntItems.bind(this))
this.router.delete("/menus/:rest",this.deleteResturaunt.bind(this))
this.router.get("/menus/:rest/:item",[this.errorHandler.bind(this),this.getItem.bind(this)])
this.router.post("/menus/:rest",this.addItem.bind(this))
this.router.delete("/menus/:rest/:item",this.deleteItem.bind(this))
```

Server-routing.ts (function):

```
public async getResturauntItems(request, response) : Promise<void> {
    console.log("Getting Restaurant Items")
    let rest = request.params.rest
    let obj = await this.theDatabase.getResturauntItems(rest)
    console.log(obj)
    response.status(201).send(JSON.stringify(obj))
    response.end()
}
```

So, what should happen is a button calls readMenu(), it then makes a GET fetch request to localhost:8080/api/menus/ and then the menu items from the  collection should be returned. The issue is that when I click the button, nothing happens. I know it is not being redirected to some other function as they all have "console.log()" to keep track of them and none of them where called. I used the "inspect" tool to see if the request was being sent or received anywhere and nothing. I am unsure of what the issue happens to be. If anyone can help, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I think we need some more context to help you in the right way, for example, what kind of frameworks are you using or how are you calling that `readMenu` function. By the way, `readMenu`  function returns another function which has to be called as well.

Answer (score 0):

you just never called your function, you declared the async function inside your function but never called it.

```
function readMenu(rest){
(async () => {
    // const newURL = url + "/menus/"+rest
    const resp = await fetch(url+"/menus/"+rest)
    const j = await resp.json();


    itemlist = j["items"]
    var element = document.getElementById("menu")
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {
        var para = document.createElement("p")
        item = itemList[i]
        text = item["name"]+" | "+item["cost"]+" | "+item["descr"] +"<br>";
        var node = document.createTextNode(text)
        para.appendChild(node)
        element.appendChild(para)
    }
})();
```

}

you need to add () after creating the functions to call it.